# inserting row or record in swing jtable after numbers of rows inside

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm newer to java as am a migrant from vb6 presnelty I'm shifting my staff and old equipments for last 15 years to Java now i would to load data isnide my Jtable relay on No. of records i mean i want to test where is the current records inside my Jtable and then upload my records behind that line my functions as per here under i used jtable number of row but it gave me error message

```
public void LoadLineInJtable(){
    int RowNo= jTable1.getModel().getRowCount(); 
    jTable1.setValueAt(jTjournal_submain_no.getText(), RowNo+1, 0);
    jTable1.setValueAt(jTjournal_submain_name.getText(), RowNo+1, 1);     
}
```

when trying with above code gave me below error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 >= 8
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
```

thank you for your input .

Comment: Please note changes to answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft what you mean , "Please note changes to answer"?

Comment: My answer has changed since I initially presented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JTable's row count is RowNum (which you should rename rowNum to comply with Java naming standards), and then you try to set values at a row that doesn't yet exist. Understand that JTable rows are 0 based, like Java arrays, and so you cannot manipulate the data of anything beyond the rowCount - 1.

If you want to add a row, you must use either the `addRow(...)` if your model is a DefaultTableModel or a child of this class, or else use your own add row method if you're using a custom table model.

So you might want something like this:

```
public void LoadLineInJtable(){
    // get data and put into array or Vector
    String[] dataRow = { 
        jTjournal_submain_no.getText(), 
        jTjournal_submain_name.getText() 
    };

    // get table model and cast it to a DefaultTableModel
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    // add row to model
    model.addRow(dataRow);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this to add a new row at the end of table:

```
((DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel()).addRow(new String[]{"column1","column2"});
```